# Can I re-enter the US if I lost my passport that has my visa?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, lost-documents, vietnamese-citizens

I'm from Vietnam and am not a US citizen. I returned to Vietnam for a visit, but I  I lost my passport that has my US visa sticker in it. I still have my Green Card. Can I go back to the US with just that?

Comment: How long have you been away from the US?

Comment: What kind of visa? Are you talking about the SB1 (returning resident)? Otherwize, please, explain how is the US visa relevant to your entry on a green card?

Comment: I'm away from the US for 2 weeks. I'm a US permanent resident. Many people told me that if I wanted to leave Vietnam, I need the passport and the US visa that verify the allowance for coming back to the US

Comment: "Many people told me that if I wanted to leave Vietnam, I need the passport and the US visa that verify the allowance for coming back to the US" They don't know what they're talking about - it's just plain wrong. See my answer'

Answer (score 3):

The US will allow you to re-enter with only your green card, unless you have lost your permanent residence status (more below).  Vietnam may require you to have a passport before you leave, however, as will the countries through which you are transiting, if any.  You should probably get a passport before you leave.

Whether you need to replace the US visa before you return depends on what kind of visa it was.

- If it was the immigrant visa you used to immigrate to the US, you do not need to replace it, because it was already replaced by your green card.
- If it was an unused returning resident visa, you should replace it

More precisely, whether you need a visa to enter the US depends on the rules for the [loss of permanent residence](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/after-green-card-granted/maintaining-permanent-residence):

> Abandoning Permanent Resident Status
>
> You may also lose your permanent resident status by intentionally abandoning it. You may be found to have abandoned your status if you:
>
> - Move to another country, intending to live there permanently.
> - Remain outside of the United States for an extended period of time, unless you intended this to be a temporary absence, as shown by:
>
>   - The reason for your trip;
>   - How long you intended to be absent from the United States;
>   - Any other circumstances of your absence; and
>   - Any events that may have prolonged your absence.
>   - Note: Obtaining a re-entry permit from USCIS before you leave, or a returning resident visa (SB-1) from a U.S. consulate while abroad, may assist you in showing that you intended only a temporary absence.
> - Fail to file income tax returns while living outside of the United States for any period.
> - Declare yourself a “nonimmigrant” on your U.S. tax returns.

If you have abandoned your permanent resident status, you cannot use your green card to enter the US.  In that case, you will need a visa.

If you have been outside the US for more than a year, you will need a new immigrant visa, called a [returning resident visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/immigrate/returning-residents.html).

Comment: Note that whether the green card can be used for re-entry and whether residence is abandoned are two separate things. The green card is not valid for re-entry after an absence of more than one year, but that doesn't mean residence is abandoned. The person may have another document that allows re-entry like an unexpired re-entry permit. Or, the person might choose to travel to the US with no document that allows re-entry and the immigration officer or an immigration judge can let the person in anyway if they determine that he/she did not abandon residence.

Comment: Vietnam does not require a passport for US resident Vietnamese. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=US&SECTION=PA&SUBSECTION=PT&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines:

> Passport exemptions: Passengers with a Permanent Resident/Resident Alien Card
>     (Form I-551).

For [Vietnamese](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=vn&SECTION=PA&SUBSECTION=PT&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C) border control:

> Passport Exemptions:
>   - Nationals of Viet Nam residing in the USA with a Certificate
>     of Visa Exemption together with:
>     a US Permanent Resident Card (Form I-551)

So if you can get a Certificate of Visa exemption (required to exit Vietnam), then you do **not** need a passport to to travel, only a Green card, although some US officials have been known to require a passport. If they (incorrectly) tell you you cannot re-enter the US without one, ask for their supervisor.